# visual puzzle with a twist

Tags: visual

[image: question no.16]

The puzzle is found on this [website](https://braining.gr/iqtest/%CF%84%CE%B5%CF%83%CF%84-iq-%CE%BC%CE%B5%CF%84%CF%81%CE%AE%CF%83%CF%84%CE%B5-%CE%B4%CE%B5%CE%AF%CE%BA%CF%84%CE%B7-%CE%BD%CE%BF%CE%B7%CE%BC%CE%BF%CF%83%CF%8D%CE%BD%CE%B7%CF%82-wechsler.html). However, instead of selecting the answer from a list of choices (which is omitted), you're expected to present it. It does not have to be an image; any format that describes the color in each square would suffice.

For reference, the colors of the first grid are, respectively, black, grey, blue, pink, brown, green, lime, tan, and orange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each color is slid 4 tiles left, making it finally :

> Brown pink blue
> Grey black orange
> Yellow teal green